# Различие между "таксой" и "стоимостью"

Tags: семантика

Можно ли употреблять слова "такса", "ставка", "тариф" в отношении к продуктам питания?

Такса на картофель, на рис.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современном значении всё-таки речь идёт о цене на картофель, на рис.

> Цена (англ. price) - денежное выражение стоимости товара, определяемое
>   затратами на его производство, а также соотношением спроса и
>   предложения на рынке.

Словарь бизнес-терминов. Академик.ру. 2001.

Когда-то слово такса употреблялось и по отношению к продуктам питания:

> 1. ТАКСА ж. франц. расценка, расписанье ценам; таксация постановленье цен вещам, оценка, расценка. Лесная таксация, расценка, определенье
>      стоимости лесов. Такса на говядину, установленье цены от
>      правительства.

Толковый словарь Даля:

Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/economics_terms/%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9A%D0%A1%D0%90

> ТАКСА - точно установленная высшей властью расценка ч.-л.; нпр., такса
>   на хлеб, на мясо, извозчичья такса, дровяная, такса вознаграждения
>   священнослужителей за требы, аптекарская, врачебная и т. д.

Полный словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в употребление в русском языке.- Попов М., 1907. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/34919/%D0%A2%D0%90%D0%9A%D0%A1%D0%90

Собственно, значение слова остаётся тем же и сейчас, но вот о **точно установленной расценке** на  картофель и рис говорить не приходится, цена на них везде разная, таксы нет.

Слово **«тариф»** происходит от названия города Тарифы, расположенного вблизи Гибралтарского пролива. Когда-то оба берега пролива принадлежали арабам, и арабы установили по особой таблице денежный сбор со всех судов, проходивших через пролив. Тариф (фр. tarif < араб. ta rifa) - объявление о пошлинных сборах. В сущности эта таблица была **перечнем пошлин – таможенных тарифов**, которые нужно было платить с экспорта или импорта товаров.

Со временем, помимо таможенных пошлин и налогов, тарифом стали называть любой **перечень цен на товары и услуги,** в частности, свод ставок обложения, оплаты чего-либо, сборов с чего-либо. **Сегодня так называется система ставок платы за перевоз грузов и пассажиров,  за электроэнергию, за различные услуги (производственные и непроизводственные), предоставляемые гражданам, организациям, учреждениям и предприятиям, ставки  оплаты труда, на основе которой устанавливается расценка каждого вида работ; взносы на государственное страхование.**

Таким образом, «цена» - более общее название, охватывающее разные понятия, такие как плата, прайс, курс,  расценка, ценность, стоимость, такса, тариф и др. А **«тариф» – более узкое название стоимости периодических денежных сборов в качестве оплаты за услуги, оказываемые за длительное время их предоставления.**

Тариф - это совокупность услуг и условий их получения и использования. К примеру, определенное количество минут разговора, СМСок, других каких-нибудь фишек, наличие бонусных баллов и проч. за определенный период времени (если говорить о мобильной связи). А цена - это то, что мы за использование этого тарифа заплатим. Не устраивает цена - выбираем другой тариф.

Можно рассмотреть эти понятия в связи с авиационными перевозками.

**Стоимость** перелета включает в себя две составляющие. Первая – это **тарифы**, а вторая – **собственно сборы и таксы.** Какая сумма получится при покупке авиабилета, зависит от многих факторов.

> Под тарифом авиакомпании подразумевают цену самого перелета. Тариф для
>   своих услуг определяет каждая авиалиния. На его величину влияют
>   политика авиакомпании, продолжительность рейса, протяженность
>   маршрута, класс комфортности и сезон. Существует также международная
>   тарифная политика.

Источник: https://nasamoletah.ru/doroga/aviaperelet/taksy-v-aviabiletah-s7.html

Какие расходы включены в таксу?

> В основном в размер таксы включается обслуживание аэропорта и
>   самолетов. Но некоторые из них покрывают и другие расходы авиакомпании
>   – например, плата за неявку пассажира, за каждый пункт прилета и
>   вылета (при рейсах с пересадками), предварительное бронирование места
>   в самолете, предоставление специального питания, ценный багаж, отдых в
>   ВИП-зале, возврат авиабилета и др. Это зависит от типа таксы.

Источник: https://nasamoletah.ru/doroga/aviaperelet/taksy-v-aviabiletah-s7.html